# Question both closed and locked?

Tags: discussion

Why was [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/71805/11281) not only closed, but *locked* as well?

I wanted to add a comment explaining that his "problem" was really a non-issue (pool heating is actually more efficient if you limit the temperature rise in the collection pipes), but now I can't even do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was originally posted on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). It was closed there (using their equivalent of the "shop-for-me" reason that many sites have), then migrated here. Since it's off-topic here (again because it's "shop-for-me"), it was closed as such; this rejects the migration, which also locks the copy here on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). That's just the way that migration works.

However, rejecting the migration unlocks the question on the originating site, so if you really want to leave a comment for the OP, there's a link to it in the "Migrated from... " notice underneath the question on the copy here. Clicking on that link will bring you to the revision history, then click on "Return to question".